# GCM push to offline devices

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I have an Android app capable of receiving two different types of Push messages. Our backend server, depending on its business rules generates these messages with appropriate Payload, no collapse keys (do not collapse) but different TTL ( first message lives only for an hour and other for 24 hour).

Everything works fine when the Android device is connected to a network.

However, when the device is not connected to the internet, and if it happens to receive messages of both types, when the device is brought online it only seems to receive message with longer TTL.

Can someone share insight to what is going on here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming that you're connecting the device to internet after TTL (time to live) has elapsed.

In that case, if your device doesn't come online for an hour, GCM will discard that message, which is exactly what is happening in your case.

Is your first message getting discarded even before TTL elapses and you get the device online?

Comment: No, the device is offline only for 10 minutes.